# Why is my [foo*-bar] tag not giving me results anymore?

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

I have a favorite tag [[tag:ie*-bug]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie*-bug) which doesn't match the right questions anymore. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ie*-bug] tags were merged into the [internet-explorer-*] tags over a year ago (on January 18, 2014 to be exact).

Since your wildcard search does not actually match any tags that currently exist in the system, the search term gets dropped and just returns all questions (since you have no other search terms).

Comment: I guess that makes sense. If I had a feedback to do Id say you should add the fact that a tag is a synonym (or show its *master*) on the tag result page.